# modify jquery autocomplete external data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I need to recreate a web app, only **for demo purposes**. This demo will not be mounted in any `server`, but as a bunch of files inside a folder.

So, i need to change this script:

```
$(newObject).autocomplete('search.php', {
        minChars: 1,
        max: 10
    });
```

to some `lorem ipsum` values. I think i need to create a variable with the dummy data, but i can't achieve that.

The js shows data over inputs that are dinamically created.

The jquery used are:

```
 jquery 1.4.2 
 jquery-ui 1.8.1 
 jquery.autocomplete 
 jquery.json 2.3 
 jquery.blockui
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does search.php return currently? e.g. If I type in "A", could it return "Apple"? If so, just make the file it calls return static values SIMILAR to what you would type in for the demo.

Comment: @MindingData i can't use external files, because certain browsers could block that. That's why i need to change the external query to an inside one

Comment: so, you need to specify the values using a variable is that it?

Comment: is the autocomplete plugin a different one than the one from jquery ui project?

Comment: @ArunPJohny exactly! but i couldn't do it. i tried to change it using the examples in http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ but i'm missing something

Comment: @Javi why do you include `jquery-ui` and `jquery.autocomplete`? I think you are using a different plugin

Comment: @ArunPJohny i think is not different at all, but as i'm not the developer who made this app, i can't tell that for sure

Comment: @Javi without knowing the plugin used we won't of much help. can you open the the `jquery.autocomplete ` and see whether it is from jQuery UI project

Comment: this is the header of jquery.autocomplete:

/*
 * jQuery Autocomplete plugin 1.1
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Jörn Zaefferer
 *
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *   http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
 *
 * Revision: $Id: jquery.autocomplete.js,v 1.3.14.1 2013/02/21 13:20:35 nv111183 Exp $
 */

Comment: @ArunPJohny as i'm not the developer of the web app, i can't tell you why are included jquery-ui and jquery.autocomplete.

I tried to simply get rid of the calling to search.php, but none of the codes used worked at all

Comment: From what I can see you are using this plugin http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the script just for demo purposes, why don't you just change it to something like this:

```
<script>
   $(function() {
      var availableTags = [
         "ActionScript",
         "AppleScript",
         "Asp",
         "BASIC",
         "C",
         "C++",
         "Clojure",
         "COBOL",
         "ColdFusion",
         "Erlang",
         "Fortran",
         "Groovy",
         "Haskell",
         "Java",
         "JavaScript",
         "Lisp",
         "Perl",
         "PHP",
         "Python",
         "Ruby",
         "Scala",
         "Scheme"
      ];
      $( newObject ).autocomplete({
         source: availableTags
         minChars: 1,
         max: 10
      });
   });
</script>
```

You can then change the tags to whatever you need for demo purposes.

Comment: Sorry the delay, i was sleeping.

I tried that, but for some reason i couldn't make it work. The code i wrote it was exactly the same you are showing to me (the example in jqueryui.com/autocomplete)

Comment: In addition, that same code was the one i used on another section of the demo, with statics inputs and it works just perfect.

Comment: @Javi In your code, I noticed you are passing the 'search.php' as a parameter to the autocomplete extension. Did you try the source setting for specifying the datasource or did you just try replacing that parameter with the availableTags object?

Comment: @Javi also if you are saying that you are using similar code in another part of your sample, are you sure that the selection criteria you are passing to jQuery (i.e. newObject) is initialized correctly. If you are creating the inputs dynamically, you need to make sure you attach the extension after they have been created and added to the document.